# copying a file from a remote server with php copy command

Tags: php, mamp

I am trying to `copy()` a file from a remote server with the `copy()` command as below:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $url = $_GET['url'];

    if (copy( $url, '/tmp/copy_from_url.jpeg'))
    {
        echo 'copied';
    }
?>
```

It seems to work as `copied` is displayed however there is no file to be found.

Any ideas on how I can track down the problem here?

I am running `MAMP` on `Lion` both the latest versions. The file in question is a `.jpeg` and `allow_url_fopen` is on.

Edit: the folder `Applications/MAMP/tmp` is actually a symbolic link to `/private/tmp` where the files ARE being copied but are not visible.

Is there a way to change `PHP` tmp folder?

Comment: Why did you turn notices off? Does `readfile($url)` work? Does file_exists and readfile work with the target filename after copying, in the if?

Comment: `readfile($url)` works on the remote file and returns data. `file_exists()` does not seem to return anything on the `dest` value of `copy()` the file is being copied but not saved. I don't know why I had `notices` off no errors with `notices` on.

Comment: What are the exact permissions `ls -l /tmp` of the target dir? Anything in the error.log? Does creating files via file_put_contents work?

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Jul 20 23:44 /tmp -> private/tmp`

Comment: Well, looks like ordinary processes don't have write permission then.

Comment: Mario are you going to write this up as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are your permissions `ls -l /tmp`

```
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root wheel 11 Jul 20 23:44 /tmp -> private/tmp – ian 9 hours
```

That looks like ordinary processes don't have write permission then. The last `r-x` means that te `other users` (not `root` or `wheel` group) lack the `w` write right. Usually Apache runs under a separate accounts, which is why PHP also cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be fine, but i think had better using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` to more reliable reason, like

```
<?php
$source = $url;
$destination = '/tmp/copy_from_url.jpeg';

$data = file_get_contents($source);

$handle = fopen($destination, "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

see if that work ?

Comment: I am sure that will work but I am trying to use `copy()` rather than `fopen` or `cURL`

Comment: there is some security issues about `copy()` your code is work fine, i have tried it before, using ubuntu 11.04 is work fine, maybe there is some security config in the mamp of lion,

Comment: Your code works without any errors but also does not write. Maybe `PHP` has the wrong permissions for the `tmp` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should change users for apache and mysql server in MAMP setting from 'www/mysql' to 'user/user' where 'user' is you mac os user - http://screencast.com/t/wzyPmFTmj6LC